# How to install Mesa agent based Modelling with Pycharm?

Tags: python, agent, multi-agent, mesa-abm

I am currently using Pycharm, and I want to use mesa package for agent based modelling, is it possible ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mesa is a library, you can install it using

```bash
pip install mesa
```

Then you will be able to use it regardless of the IDE.